# Error when passing values from nodejs to ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

server.js

From server I am trying to pass stripePublickey to pricing.ejs as shown in the below code but the value is not getting passed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const stripePublickey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY

res.render('pricing.ejs', {
      stripePublickey: stripePublickey,
      items: JSON.parse(data)
})
```

pricing.ejs

```
In pricing.ejs I am trying to get like this

<script>
      var stripePublicKey = '<%= stripePublicKey %>'      
</script>
```

but this is the error I get

```
Reference error:  var stripePublicKey = '<%= stripePublicKey %>'
```

Comment: Replacing quotes(') with double quotes(") will resolve this issue.

Comment: So please modify like this ```var stripePublicKey = "<%= stripePublicKey %>"```